# How to fix the variable names in a simplenews subscription confirmation mail?

Tags: 7, emails

I have a [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) subscription block for the anonymous users of my site. When they enter their name and email address and hit subscribe, a mail is sent to their email ID for confirmation. It is a single confirmation email.

When i see the mail it displays the variable names that i am using. 
For eg :

> 1) The subject of the mail is Confirmation for !newsletter_name.
>   2) please use the link below, then click "Subscribe" on the web page that
>   will open: !confirm_subscribe_url

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing you upgraded from D6. The tokens you are using are D6 tokens.

Go to **/admin/config/services/simplenews/settings/subscription** and change the tokens. For instance, the default subject for D7 is :

```
Confirmation for [simplenews-category:name] from [site:name]
```

Note the new (D7) token format. You can find he new tokens by expanding 'Replacement patterns'.